# Memoryless distributions that are neither discrete or continuous

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The [Wikipedia page for memorylessness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness)
goes over arguments that only the geometric and exponential distributions are memoryless, if we stick to just discrete and continuous distributions. What about mixed distributions? Is memorylessness such a nice property that nothing as ugly as a mixed distribution would have it? Or is there some crazy CDF out there that is discontinuous at every rational number and yet somehow manages to be memoryless? The world of mixed distributions seems so large, and weird, that I don't really know what to think.

Is there a general classification of memoryless mixed distributions? Or else some results in that direction?

Comment: The geometric distribution is memoryless on its support (the positive integers times some positive constant which is usually taken to be $1$).  A mixed distribution would have a continuous support somewhere, and if memoryless then the support would then have to be on all the positive reals, and that would take you to the exponential distribution.

Comment: Building off of Henry's comment I think this question is probably going to be more interesting over with non-integer dimensional support then for mixed distributions.